# LoadedCommand is called when view is unloaded

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, prism

I've got a behavior in my .net Core 3.1 WPF Application, which calls a command inside the ViewModel, after the view is displayed.

```
public class LoadedBehavior
{
   public static DependencyProperty LoadedCommandProperty
      = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
         "LoadedCommand",
         typeof(ICommand),
         typeof(LoadedBehavior),
         new PropertyMetadata(null, OnLoadedCommandChanged));

   private static void OnLoadedCommandChanged
      (DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (depObj is FrameworkElement frameworkElement && e.NewValue is ICommand)
      {
         frameworkElement.Loaded
            += (o, args) => { (e.NewValue as ICommand)?.Execute(null); };
      }
   }

   public static ICommand GetLoadedCommand(DependencyObject depObj)
   {
      return (ICommand)depObj.GetValue(LoadedCommandProperty);
   }

   public static void SetLoadedCommand(
      DependencyObject depObj,
      ICommand value)
   {
      depObj.SetValue(LoadedCommandProperty, value);
   }
}
```

This Behavior is attached inside the View:

```xaml
behaviors:LoadedBehavior.LoadedCommand="{Binding LoadedCommand}"
```

I am working with Prisms RegionManager to inject my Views into specific areas inside the views. When I now try to inject a new view, the loaded command from the old view is called again. This seems like it comes from the bevavior.

For a better understanding, here is also the code which gets called to show a new view inside the specific region

```
public class NavigationService
{
   private readonly IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;
   private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

   public NavigationService(IServiceLocator serviceLocator, IRegionManager regionManager)
   {
      _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
      _regionManager = regionManager;
   }

   public void Navigate(string regionName, object view)
   {
      RemoveAllViews(regionName);
      _regionManager.AddToRegion(regionName, view);
   }

   public void Navigate<T>(string regionName) where T : FrameworkElement
   {
      var view = _serviceLocator.GetInstance<T>();
      Navigate(regionName, view);
   }

   public void RemoveAllViews(string regionName)
   {
      _regionManager.Regions[regionName].RemoveAll();
   }
}
```

Can anyone tell me, what I do wrong here? Or is this behavior not the way to go?

### Edit

Right after posting this, I found the problem: The Loaded Command gets called multiple times. This seems to be caused by when the content of this view changes. So everytime I add a new view, the parent view calls it's loaded event. Is there a way to run the command only once the view is displayed?

Comment: If it's the command out the "old" viewmodel then this is presumably still the datacontext of the view. I'm not really a fan of prism generally because of it's complexity. This is particularly true of regions and regionmanager. 99% of the time, any Initialisation logic should go in the viewmodel.

Comment: Well Prism works quiet good for all of my applications I am writing, and I never had such a weird problem. So I think I am doing something wrong here.. I added the code which is called when I want to show a new View inside the region.. maybe this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Loaded` event is quite inreliable for triggering action with the intention of *one time when the control is loaded*. From the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.loaded?view=netcore-3.1) of the `Loaded` event for `FrameworkElement`.

> Loaded and Unloaded might both be raised on controls as a result of user-initiated system theme changes. A theme change causes an invalidation of the control template and the contained visual tree, which in turn causes the entire control to unload and reload. **Therefore Loaded cannot be assumed to occur only when a page is first loaded through navigation to the page.**

In Prism you can act on navigation by creating a custom region behavior. In your example, you want to execute a command on a view model, once the view is added to a region. Create an interface that all your target view models implement with a command that should be executed when the view is displayed first.

```
public interface IInitializableViewModel
{
   ICommand Initialize { get; }
}
```

Create a region behavior that watches the `Views` collection of a region and executes a command once, when a view is added to the region. It will check the data context of each view, if it implements the interface, the command is not null and command can execute.

```
public class InitializableDataContextRegionBehavior : RegionBehavior
{
   public const string BehaviorKey = nameof(InitializableDataContextRegionBehavior);

   protected override void OnAttach()
   {
      Region.Views.CollectionChanged += OnViewsCollectionChanged;
   }

   private void OnViewsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
      {
         foreach (var frameworkElement in e.NewItems.OfType<FrameworkElement>())
         {
            if (frameworkElement.DataContext is IInitializableViewModel initializableViewModel &&
                initializableViewModel.Initialize != null &&
                initializableViewModel.Initialize.CanExecute(null))
            {
               initializableViewModel.Initialize.Execute(null);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Add the custom region behavior in your Prism application to the region behaviors collection.

```
protected override void ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors(IRegionBehaviorFactory regionBehaviors)
{
   base.ConfigureDefaultRegionBehaviors(regionBehaviors);
   regionBehaviors.AddIfMissing(InitializableDataContextRegionBehavior.BehaviorKey, typeof(InitializableDataContextRegionBehavior));
}
```

The command on each view model will execute exactly once, when the corresponding view is added to any region. Using an interface here was easier for demonstration purposes, but you can also create an attached property for your command that you attach to your view and bind to the view model.

Comment: I didn't even know such an overridable method exists.. I have tested it, and it works like a charm. With this way of implementation, I am able to add the views to regions when the View has loaded..  Many thanks for your help!